# How to enable libMagick++ in order to save .png file format

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, cimg

I have written a c++ program that read, add noise and save image. I can save image in .bmp but when try to save image in .png, the error pops up saying 
**...Unable to save file 'noisy-canon.png' unless libMagick++ is enabled**

See my code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <CImg.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
        //image file
        CImg<unsigned char> image("milla.png");
        image.noise(5,2);
        image.save_magick("noisy-canon.png");
        CImgDisplay main_disp(image, "Image with Pepper noise",0);
        while (!main_disp.is_closed())
            {
                main_disp.wait();
            }
        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

I also tried to use save_cimg(). It creates a file, with error saying

**...Unable to save compressed data in file 'noisy_canon.png' unless zlib is enabled, saving them uncompressed.**

Below is my code;

```
(...)

image.save_cimg("noisy_canon.png",1);

(...)
```

Below attempts where tried with no success;

```
//above cimg.h "this gives error"
#define cimg_use_png  
#include <CImg.h>

//tried below cimg.h "no error, but doesn't work"
#include <CImg.h>
#define cimg_use_png
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Me not being a user of magick++, let's look at this logically.  Either 1) you're using a version of magick++ that has stubbed out the zlib code with an `#ifdef` that is false , or 2) magick++ can't find the zlib dynamic link library or plugin at runtime, or 3) you have to call a function to load the zlib library/plug-in yourself.  Those 3 scenarios are the most likely.

Comment: @ThomasSablik...i have edited the question. Review it

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie...i will check on your suggestions...thanks

Comment: Why are you using ImageMagick at all? Just install `libpng` and `zlib` and you're good to go. Don't include `Magick++.h` at all.

Comment: Also, there's absolutely no point defining `cimg_use_png` **after** `#include <CImg.h>` You are better off defining it on your compilation command-line.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie...tried to check all options but is till get the same error

Comment: @MarkSetchell...thanks for reply. i have included all libraries (libpng and zlib) but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the alternative to libMagick++. Since it is installed on the machine, I used the terminal/command version to convert.

```
system("convert input.jpg output.png");
```